# Emacs completion through symlink (OSX)

Tags: osx, completion, symbolic-links

I have a symlink on my Desktop that points to my Dropbox folder. Clicking on this link takes me through to Dropbox, which is located elsewhere. But if I try navigating to `~/Desktop/Dropbox` using Emacs, it tells me that the symlink is the sole completion and will not go further.

[image]

How can I get Emacs to let me to `TAB` through the symlink, so that I can start with `~/Desktop` and then navigate to say:

`~/Desktop/Dropbox/folder/inside/Dropbox/...`?

Comment: What happens if you hit `RET` for that sole completion?

Comment: Emacs opens the Symlink file itself.

Comment: Not clear to me; maybe show an example? You say you have a symlink to a *folder*, but in your comment you speak of a symlink to a *file*.

Comment: The symlink is a file of sorts, with instructions that point somewhere else. When I try to open the symlink in Emacs, it is actually opens the symlink itself, instead of the folder that it points to. If that makes sense?

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean now. I still suggest you show an example. Just a suggestion.

Comment: All done. Thanks @Drew!

Comment: Is it really a symbolic link? What do you see when you open it in Emacs? What is the output of `file ~/Desktop/Dropbox` and of `file -L ~/Desktop/Dropbox` ?

Comment: To me looks like it's a OSX finder alias and not a unix symlink. At least a while ago when I had a mac finder handled both equally but at system level they're not the same, aliases are seen like regular files. Try to create a symlink with `ln -s`

Comment: That did it! You are correct, it was an Alias. When I changed it to a soft link, completion worked. So is there a way to also make this work with Finder aliases?

Comment: Please, @Muihlinn or OP: post the answer as an answer, to help others. Comments can be deleted at any time, and they are not searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your symlink is a finder alias and not a symlink. OSX Finder handles both of them the same way, but at system level the finder alias is a plain file.

Substitute the finder alias for a proper unix symlink using `ln -s` command and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Muihlinn.  I don’t suppose there a supported method to complete through a Finder alias as well?

Comment: I don't know, I packed up about 10.7.5 and then if something like that existed I wasn't aware of it . IIRC Finder aliases at early OSXs were part of Mac OS 9 compatibility using the Resource Fork for storing targets. Why they keep both kinds behaving diferently depending if you're using the Finder, the CLI or a system call was something acceptable at first, but after 10.4 a plain annoyance.